# Convert hex to binary while retaining their places

Tags: vb.net, binary, hex, type-conversion

I have this code that converts `7` to binary.

```
Dim s As String = "7"
Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16)
Dim s2 As String = Convert.ToString(i, 2)
Console.WriteLine(s2) 'result is 111
```

My problem is this, I want to apply the 8 bit binary so I can easily substring the result.

Instead of the result that is `111`, I would like to make it `0111`.

Examples:

Binary / Hex

```
 1. F = 1111
 2. 7 = 0111
 3. 1 = 0001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad the result with starting zero by using [**PadLeft**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
s2.PadLeft(4, "0")
```